# Language of Regular Expression

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I'm trying to teach myself Regular expressions for Automata,

I'm struggling to work out what the output of

$L((1+01)^*)$ would be

Would it be the star closure of $\{1,01\}$ or star closure of $\{1,0,1\}$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$L(1+01)=\{1,01\}$, so it’s the star closure of $\{1,01\}$, which consists of all strings over the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ in which every $0$ (if there is one) is immediately followed by a $1$.

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it's 5:20 am here so I am struggling to concentrate.

Comment: But yeah, that's what I'm looking for, so say there is no single 1, then if there is a 0 it must be followed by a 1? ie {lamba,01}?

Comment: @Danny: Any string that either has no zeroes at all or has every $0$ immediately followed by a $1$ is in the language: $1111$, $1101101$, and $0101111011$ are all in the language, for instance, but $110$ and $11001$ are not.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your quick response and help. Will mark as correct when I wake up as it's giving me a time limit at the moment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Danny: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way - let $\alpha = 1 + 01$. Therefore, $L = \alpha^\star$. That is, $L$ consists of $\lambda$, the empty string, and one or more $\alpha$. But $\alpha$, in turn, is either $1$ or $01$. This is exactly the language that the previous reply describes.

Answer (score 0):

The star closure of $\{1,0,1\}$ is the star closure of $\{0,1\}$, because $\{1,0,1\} = \{0,1\}$. Clearly that language is not $L((1+01)^*)$, which is all strings over $\{0,1\}$ with no two consecutive $0$s.